# How do I delete an old device from my Google Acct?

Tags: google-account, google

so I have given my old phone to my mom and have forgotten to remove the my gmail account. I want to delete the phone from the "approved" list but I cannot find a way to delete it.

I've looked at various guides and the options/settings they are talking about are not available anymore.

I am looking at this page: https://myaccount.google.com/device-activity

Any ideas?

I'm trying to avoid changing my password since that means I need to change that on all my devices.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

If you are unable to remove the device from the `Device activity` section of your Google account because the red button doesn't show up, go instead to [Google Security Checkup](https://myaccount.google.com/security-checkup) and expand `Your devices`, then tap on the 3 dots on the side of the device you want to remove to select the option.

Answer (score 5):

It's quite easy. Click on the device you wish to remove and confirm as shown in screenshot below from my list of devices

[image]
[image]

**Edit** Try signing out of that account and signing in from that old phone and check if it shows up. Interestingly, for some users the *remove* button is not visible and there is an [ongoing bug report](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/play/GNrjCjuoaSQ) for more than a year. You may like to add your complaint the and follow for updates

Comment: I don't see that option.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what you see and is the device you wish to remove listed or not?

Comment: Please see edit...

Comment: Afaik the remove button only comes for devices that haven't been logged into the account for long enough.

Comment: @xdevs23: That's not the case. Lollipop onwards if you want to factory reset you need to remove device from account to avoid factory reset protection lock. But *showing* devices used to be restricted to ascribe within last one month but that also changed - as you can see in the snapshot you see devices not active for more than a month

Comment: Alright then, didn't know that

Answer (score 0):

1.) When I tried it via google.com/device-activity, the unknown device is listed, last used 4 days ago. The option to remove the unknown device is not available (i.e. no option to remove it, no 'red button'). However it does state that any unused devices after 28 days will be removed from the list. I changed my password 3 days ago.

2.) Going thru the "google security checkup" route, it only shows me a list of actively used devices, which does not include the foreign device.

So, I assume Google is the one who will "remove" the unknown device off my "device activity" list in 24 days. As long as I've changed my password I should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

@reddy-lutonadio and to anyone else that seems to have the same problem I did just now, I had an unrecognized device on my account, a phone I have never owned, and the remove button did not exist, nor did the suggested fix you presented here work either, however, per the suggestion you gave, I discovered that a work-around did exist per your guided tip, however the remove option is not what was shown, sign out was the option needed that did the same job per your recommended link.  thank you, and if anyone else sees that same issue, you can follow that link, but click sign out of device instead.